# Convert floating point number to scientific format with fixed exponent

Tags: python, matplotlib, format, axis

I would like to convert the following:

```
0.00000012 to 0.1e-6 
0.0000012  to 1.2e-6
```

and found:

> '%.1e' % var

which does

```
0.00000012 to  1.2e-7
0.0000012  to  1.2e-6
```

How can i format to keep the exponent fixed?

How can i apply the same format to the matplotlib ticks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this (you need to define the requested precision):

```
number_to_convert = 0.00000012
precision = 3
print ("%0.*e"%(precision,number_to_convert))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`plt.ticklabel_format`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format). Here is a MWE.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(2)
y = [0.00000012, 0.0000012]
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xticks(x)
plt.yticks(y)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0, 0))

plt.show()
```

which produce,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To format numbers use the following way:

```
>>> for i in [.12e9,1.2e9,12e9,120e9]:
...     print('{:.3e} => {:0=5.3f}e9'.format(i, i/1e9))

1.200e+08 => 0.120e9
1.200e+09 => 1.200e9
1.200e+10 => 12.000e9
1.200e+11 => 120.000e9
```

See [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). `{:0=5.3f}` means "zero-pad, pad between the sign and the number, total field width 8, 3 places after the decimal, fixed point format".